# ActiveMQ Artemis use-duplicate-detection causes AMQ214019: Invalid configuration: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: activemq-artemis

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server 64bit
- OpenJDK 11.0.15
- ActiveMQ Artemis 2.21.0

According to the [clustering documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.21.0/clusters.html) I can use duplicate message detection in `cluster-connection`. However, because I don't need the cluster connection to detect duplicate messages I add `<use-duplicate-detection>false</use-duplicate-detection>` in the `broker.xml`.

When I run `artemis-service start` I get this error:

```
2022-07-31 18:52:02,335 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214019: Invalid configuration: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"urn:activemq:core":use-duplicate-detection}'. One of '{"urn:activemq:core":max-hops, "urn:activemq:core":confirmation-window-size, "urn:activemq:core":producer-window-size, "urn:activemq:core":call-failover-timeout, "urn:activemq:core":notification-interval, "urn:activemq:core":notification-attempts, "urn:activemq:core":scale-down-connector, "urn:activemq:core":static-connectors, "urn:activemq:core":discovery-group-ref}' is expected.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:511) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3587) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1971) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.beginNode(DOMValidatorHelper.java:276) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(DOMValidatorHelper.java:243) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(DOMValidatorHelper.java:189) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:108) [java.xml:]
        at java.xml/javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124) [java.xml:]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.XMLUtil.validate(XMLUtil.java:361) [artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:]
```

Below is my `broker.xml`:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      ...
      <cluster-user>cluster</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>cluster</cluster-password>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.8</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.8</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <use-duplicate-detection>false</use-duplicate-detection>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      ...
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the elements actually matters because [the ActiveMQ Artemis configuration XSD](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/artemis-server/src/main/resources/schema/artemis-configuration.xsd) defines an [`xsd:sequence`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_sequence.asp). Therefore, you should be using this:

```xml
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <use-duplicate-detection>false</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
         </cluster-connection>
```